# MWAA - Trigger a specific Dag Task from a environment using a task from other environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, mwaa

I’m trying to execute a task from one MWAA environment to another MWAA environment. If I need to execute the whole dag it’s simple and I can do it using this code:

```
@task()
def invoke_dag_task():
    client = boto3.client('mwaa')
    token = client.create_cli_token(Name='my-environment')
    url = f"https://{token['WebServerHostname']}/aws_mwaa/cli"
    body = 'dags trigger test'
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token['CliToken'],
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }
    requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
```

This code above is working perfectly. To execute only a specific task I’m using this one:

```
@task()
def invoke_dag_task():
    client = boto3.client('mwaa')
    token = client.create_cli_token(Name='my-environment')
    url = f"https://{token['WebServerHostname']}/aws_mwaa/cli"
    body = 'tasks test test task_1 2023-05-17T16:48:03Z'
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token['CliToken'],
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }
    requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
```

I don’t get any error but the task is not triggered. do you know why?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `tasks test` triggers tasks. Instead it runs them from the CLI. So the tasks will run but it won't show has triggered in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that MWAA does not support all Airflow cli commands. It looks like the tasks you have defined above are supported but these will not trigger  a task.

You can use other commands and I put together an example in [a blog post](https://dev.to/aws/interacting-with-amazon-managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow-via-the-command-line-4e91) which looks like:

```
import json
import requests
import boto3
import base64

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print("Connecting to MWaa environment" + ": " +  event['environment'])
    client = boto3.client('mwaa')
    response = client.create_cli_token(Name=str( event['environment']))

    print("Using this command" + ": " +  event['command'])

    auth_token=response.get('CliToken')
    hed = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
    data = str(args.command)
    url = 'https://{web_server}/aws_mwaa/cli'.format(web_server=response.get('WebServerHostname'))
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=hed)
    output = base64.b64decode(r.json()['stdout']).decode('utf8')
    print(output)

    return event['environment']  # Echo back the first key value
```

which you then trigger with a payload

```
{
  "environment": "{your environment}",
  "command": "{airflow command}"
}
```